Title field does not show for product
Long time user of Commerce here -- but working with a brand-new Drupal 10 install and just realizing how much I was building on prior work with my old setup.
Just created a new Product type, configured the title to show with the label hidden, but the title doesn't show.  I tried moving it lower, just to see if it was being covered by something, but no title.
I titled both the product and the variable (although there is only one variation of this product).  Any idea what is going on?  Configured display as both plain text and link just to see what happened and visible, no difference.
Thank you for your help!
-tiffani

Ok, it's a problem with the theme. I was using Drupal8 Zymphonies and it must be set for titles not to show.  Changed the theme and that problem was solved.
